# Sorting by index in another array

Tags: ruby, sorting

If I have a an array of objects like:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Orange'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Banana'}]
```

And I have an array of ids: `[3, 1, 2]`

Does Ruby have a concise and/or efficient way to sort the array by the ids in the second array like:

```
[{id: 3, name: 'Banana'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Orange'}]
```

Comment: @sawa: Editing just to change the style? I like it sparse...

Comment: @BorisStitnicky You edited just to change the style. I reverted some unnecessary changes you made. Please don't change the OP's style, especially from a well style to a non-educated person's style. An educated person would not put spaces inside parentheses, braces, or brackets (it is fine to have line endings).

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Continued:  (it is fine to have line endings or indentation). Sorry if it sounded offensive. I am not targeting particularly you. I know that many programmers do that, and I am annoyed by it.

Comment: @sawa, it's not a matter of being or not being educated. I have read many manuals of style, and I prefer readability over saving characters. I know that character spaces on an 80 character line are precious, but my brain simply doesn't read it so quickly when the parens are crammed together. So it's a matter of personal preference or personal abilities. If you can read crammed parens efficiently, congrats to you. I won't wage a revert war with you.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I am not sure if you got it correctly. It is not a matter of saving characters. It is a matter of readability. These characters are designed to surround something, and they are designed to look beautiful when put right next to their content without spaces in between. Moreover, no Manual of Style book will tell you to put spaces inside them. And following these rules is what an educated person is expected to do. You and I agree that it should be for readability/beauty, but we seem to have opposite senses.

Comment: @sawa, good we agree on something, but don't claim that no manual will tell you to put spaces inside parens if you didn't read all of them. And you obviously haven't, because [this good manual](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml) by a Google engineer tells you to put spaces inside [curly braces](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#blocks), inside [rounded parens](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#horizwhite), and even shows them inside array-constructing [square braces](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#ri).

Comment: @sawa, now that I have sourced my claims, could you tell me how did you arrive to the proposition that parens are designed to look beautiful when put right next to their content without spaces in between? Because although I can imagine such design intent, the reality of parens for me is different...

Comment: @BorisStitnicky What you cited is just something that an individual wrote for internal use in a certain department of a company. It is by no means official, and it has no basis. These informal documents are easier to find on the internet as people just post whatever they want without being backed up by authority. I tried to cite something for you from Chicago's Manual of Style, but these academic things for educated people tends to be on conventional books, and the online version requires signup.

Comment: @sawa, sorry but there is _no_ official manual of style of Ruby at all. Chicago manual doesn't apply. The only requirement is that you comply with Ruby syntax. Someone may find [code by Yusuke Endoh](http://mamememo.blogspot.tw/2010/09/qlobe.html) more pleasing and readable than anything the two of us agree upon =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
a1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Apple'}, {id: 2, name: 'Orange'}, {id: 3, name: 'Banana'}]
a2 = [3,1,2]

a1.sort_by{|h| a2.index(h[:id])}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two other ways:

**#1**

```
def order_hashes1(a,order)
  a.each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g.update({h[:id]=>h}) }.values_at(*order)
end

order_hashes1(a1,a2)
  #=> [{:id=>3, :name=>"Banana"},
  #    {:id=>1, :name=>"Apple"},
  #    {:id=>2, :name=>"Orange"}]
```

**#2**

```
def order_hashes2(a,order)
  order.map { |i| a.find { |h| h[:id] == i } }
end

order_hashes2(a1,a2)
  #=> [{:id=>3, :name=>"Banana"},
  #    {:id=>1, :name=>"Apple"},
  #    {:id=>2, :name=>"Orange"}]
```

**Benchmark**

*Methods compared*

```
module Methods
  def sawa(a,order)
    a.sort_by{ |h| order.index(h[:id]) }
  end

  def order_hashes1(a,order)
    a.each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g.update({h[:id]=>h}) }.values_at(*order)
  end

  def order_hashes2(a,order)
    order.map { |i| a.find { |h| h[:id] == i } }
  end
end

include Methods
methods = Methods.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:order_hashes1, :order_hashes2, :sawa]
```

*Test data*

```
def test_data(n)
  a1 = n.times.with_object([]) { |i,a| a << { id: i, name: 'Apple' } }.shuffle
  a2 = n.times.to_a.shuffle
  [a1, a2]
end
```

*Confirm all methods return the same values*

```
a1, a2 = test_data(1_000)
result = send(method.first, a1, a2)
puts methods[1..-1].all? { |m| result = send(m,a1,a2) }
  #=> true
```

*The benchmark routine*

```
require 'benchmark'

a1, a2 = test_data(20_000)

Benchmark.bm(methods.map { |m| m.to_s.size }.max) do |bm|
  methods.each do |m|
    bm.report m.to_s do
      send(m, a1, a2)
    end
  end
end    
                    user     system      total        real
order_hashes1   0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.033169)
order_hashes2  49.300000   0.110000  49.410000 ( 49.486159)
sawa            1.500000   0.000000   1.500000 (  1.499078)
```

*Epilogue*

I was not surprised that `order_hashes2` never got out of the gate, but I was startled that building the hash and then extracting values with `values_at` was so much faster than @sawa's solution.  I expect the latter spent most of its time performing the `index` operation.

Reader challenger: there are many other ways to address this problem. Let's see your suggestions and I'll add them to the benchmark.